# Get value from oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g

I have a oracle procedure which should return a concatenated string of all the parameters

```
create or replace procedure tin_builder (type in varchar2, 
       tin_serial in number, rand_digit in varchar2, tin out varchar2 ) is 
    BEGIN
      tin := type || TO_CHAR(tin_serial) || rand_digit ;
    END
```

Now i want to call the procedure from visual studio 2008 (C# code)

```
public void TinBuilder(string type, long tin_serial, string rand_digit)
{
    OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("Data Source=xe;User ID=system;Password=******;");

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "tin_builder";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("type", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = type;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("tin_serial", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = tin_serial;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("rand_digit", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = rand_digit;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("tin", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        TextBox1.Text = cmd.Parameters["tin"].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Then called it with :

```
TinBuilder("1", 10000001, "37");
```

But it does not show any value in the text box :( . Please someone help me out.

Comment: Have you tested your sproc?  I would be using `SELECT type || TO_CHAR(tin_serial) || rand_digit INTO tin FROM DUAL;` instead of what you have.  Also - good to be explicit about parameter declaration: `tin IN OUT varchar2` rather than `tin OUT varchar2`.

Comment: I dont know why my stored procedure is not working. when i execute procedure then it shows "SQL Statement Running" !!!

Comment: Is there any specific service i should run?

Comment: What are you using - PLSQL Developer, Toad?  You need to test the sproc you created - SQL IDEs I've used have test functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Type" is a reserved word in Oracle. Here's the link: http://www.cs.umbc.edu/help/oracle8/server.815/a42525/apb.htm

And as said by  OMG Ponies change & try: SELECT type || TO_CHAR(tin_serial) || rand_digit INTO tin FROM DUAL;

And also make sure you always 'initiate' exception to catch these kind of errors

Answer (score 0):

"Type" may be a reserved word. Are you sure the procedure compiled and is valid?

Also are you catching any error messages there, and hiding them with the catch clause? That seems like bad practice.